# IS Azure subscript required to use power BI embedded ServicePrincipal login?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

```
IS Azure subscript required to use power BI embedded Service Principal login? 
I dont have subscript and I am trying to login using Service Principal login ,
it give me Unauthorized.
```

I am following this below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#assign-the-application-to-a-role

Answer (score 2):

Authenticating with service principal works and requires the [new workspaces experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-create-the-new-workspaces), i.e. you need Power BI Pro account for that. But you don't need to pay for separate Azure subscription. In Azure portal you need to [create a security group and add the registered application in it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-service-principal), which you can do for free.